# Local definition of Hölder continuity

Tags: real-analysis, definition, holder-spaces

What does it mean for a continuous function $ f $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ to be Hölder continuous with exponent $ \alpha $ at a point $ x_0 $ ?

I only now the global definition:
A function $ f $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ is (globally) Hölder continuous with exponent $ \alpha $ if

$$ \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{| f(x) - f(y) |}{ |x - y|^\alpha} < + \infty $$

Thanks for the clarification!

Regards, Si

Comment: Locally means that we can find a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that $\sup\{\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|},x,y\in V,x\neq y\}$ is finite.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: Hmmm... So if one says that Brownian motion is $P$-a.s. nowhere Hölder continuous with exponent $ \alpha > 1/2 $, is the meaning that $P$-a.s. no point $ x_0 $ has a neighborhood $ V $ such that $ \sup_{x, y \in V, x \neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|^\alpha} < + \infty $ or that no point $ x_0 $ has a neighborhood $ V $ such that $ \sup_{x \in V, x \neq x_0} \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0)|}{|x - x_0|^\alpha} < + \infty $ ? Thanks a lot Davide!

Comment: @MadSi It's the former.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as far as I remember, one calls $f$

- **Hölder continuous** of exponent $\alpha$ iff
  \[ \sup_{x,y\in\mathbb R} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} <\infty \]
- **locally Hölder continuous** of exponent $\alpha$ iff
  \[ \sup_{x,y\in K} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} <\infty \]
  for each compact $K \subset \mathbb R$
- **Hölder continuous at $x_0$** of exponent $\alpha$ iff 
  \[ \sup_{x\in U} \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|^\alpha} <\infty\]
  for some neighbourhood $U \ni x_0$.

Comment: Hence Hölder continuity at $x_0$ means exactly $f(x) = O(|x|^\alpha)$?

Comment: As far as I remember, yes, that's Hölder continuity at 0, for general $x_0$ we should write $f(x) = O(|x-x_0|^\alpha)$, $x \to x_0$.#

Comment: I think your suggestion is wrong: we should write $f(x)=f(x_0)+O(|x-x_0|^\alpha)$. Anyway, it's interesting, I had never studied Hölder continuity at a precise point.

Comment: Oh, of course you're right ...

Comment: Yes, these three definitions agree with those given in standard texts such as Gilbarg and Trudinger _Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order_, p.52

Comment: @WillieWong thx.

Answer (score 3):

As usual, the term "local" (or "locally") means that the definition should be restricted to any neighborhood. In you case, $f$ is locally Hölder continuous if, for every interval $(a,b)$ there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C |x-y|^\alpha$ for every $x$, $y \in [a,b]$. Clearly enough, this amounts to considering $f_{|[a,b]}$ instead of $f$ in the global definition. Notice that the constant $C$ depends on $(a,b)$, so the local definition is, in general, strictly different than the global one.